# PHP: Can't set variable when $_REQUEST is blank

Tags: php, post, get, request

I'm having issues with setting a variable either with using $_REQUEST or it's my syntax. When checking `$_REQUEST['orderBy']`, if it's blank/empty I want to set a default value of `'order_date'`. However, when it retrieves and empty `$_REQUEST['orderBy']` it just remains empty instead of setting it. I made an ugly fix in the code to resolve the issue later on, but I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong:

```
$orderBy = isset($_REQUEST['orderBy']) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['orderBy']) : 'order_date';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with that, but it will set `$orderBy` to an empty value if `$_REQUEST['orderBy']` is set but empty. Try using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
$orderBy = (empty($_REQUEST['orderBy'])) ? 'order_date' : $_REQUEST['orderBy'];
```

If it still doesn't work, you may be mistakenly setting `$_REQUEST['orderBy']` prior to this line. You should try to use the more specific super globals like `$_POST` and `$_GET`, both because they make your code clearer and more readable, and because they improve the security of your application.

Comment: Clearer is true. But security is a misattribution, particularly when it's about a parameter called `orderBy`

Comment: Admittedly irrelevant in this case, but I stand by the idea that not declaring where your data is coming from can introduce security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Empty fails if the value being checked can be cast to an empty string. this includes `'0'`, `' '`, `null` and the like. Not a big deal if castable-to-empty-string isn't something you need to account for, but it will trip you up sometime later on.